# How to remove part of a rowname after the second underscore

Tags: r, gsub

I want to get all the characters before the second underscore in a string. Any ideas how I can do this?

I have this:
Part1-Part2_Part3_Part4

I want this:

Part1-Part2_Part3

all the parts can vary from one another and there can also be more than 4 parts.

Comment: `sub("_([^_]*)$", "", "Part1-Part2_Part3_Part4")` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `gregexpr`.

```
str <- 'Part1-Part2_Part3_Part4'
start <- 1
end <- (unlist(gregexpr('_', str))[2] - 1)
substr(str, start, end)
```

Comment: @KerstinThol Glad that it helped! Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: why can t you just do `sub('_[^_]+$', '', str)`?

Comment: @Onyambu,  this might keep everything before the last underscore rather than the second one

Comment: It seems you do not understand regular expressions. Teach yourself some.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a lazy match with `gsub` function:

```
a = "Part1-Part2_Part3_Part4"

gsub("(.+?_.+?)_.*" ,"\\1", a)
# [1] "Part1-Part2_Part3"
```